# Two questions - Max value of each hour // "Predict" next values based on old ones

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, average, prediction

Lets say I have a table with a quantity and a timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s)

Example:

```
5 |2017-06-12 3:45:10
9 |2017-06-12 3:59:17
12|2017-06-12 4:07:27
etc.
```

I have much more values for each hour, each day and month.

What I need but couldnt figure out myself yet: How can I select only the highest value of each hour. I need this for every day (24 values) and month and so on.

Second question: Based on that data from above, I would like to suggest a value for the next time frame, but how? I am not sure how to make a good moving average as the time intervall is not always fixed (e. g. one hour) but can have sometimes 30 minutes distance and sometimes less and more than that. If I know how to "predict" future values, I would be happy to guess it for two or three values in future.

(Background: Its a User online list and I want to get the highest user record per hour and would like to predict the online count for next time frame)

I am thankful for some ideas

I like to make a prediction like shown in the image. The dotted line is a prediction for a few time frames in future: 
[image]

Comment: Something like `max(value) between date 1:00:00 and 1:59:59` ?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!